# xamarin IOS: Warning: App failed to install+launch

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I am facing the issue below,hope some one will help me out.

I am Using visual studio 2019 to run the xamarin IOS project and paired to MAC succesfully, but the simulator has failed to launch the app and throws the exception below

> System.Exception: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not find file
>   "/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TigrinyaDictionary.iOS/f5727f6bbdd6a791c1a56d7c269a65ff/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/TigrinyaDictionary.iOS.app/TigrinyaDictionary.iOS"
>        at Xamarin.Simulator.Core.Protocol.SimulatorClient.d__26.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\A_work\1703\s\Xamarin.Simulator.Core\Protocol\SimulatorClient.cs:line
>   293
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at Xamarin.Simulator.Windows.App.d__19.MoveNext() in
>   E:\A_work\1703\s\Xamarin.Simulator.Windows\App.xaml.cs:line 340
>     ErrorCode: 1008

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/130483/#Comment_130483

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your build wasn't completed successfully (errors) and the produced App bundle is incorrect.

1. I would check the build logs to see if there are any errors (for issue like this please always give your full verbose build logs).
2. I would check the App bundle on the Mac: `/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TigrinyaDictionary.iOS`. Check for completeness.
   You should be able to trace back in the build log where and why that
   wasn't generated (built).
3. I would install the latest bits of Visual Studio and the Xamarin Support, clean your project, rebuild and re-deploy.

If none of that works, you can **report a problem** directly in the IDE and that will open a feedback ticket with the Xamarin team.
Please add your full build logs (critical for an issue like this), ideally test project to reproduce and all product version information.